# What is the difference between a render pass and a pipeline in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

Can't figure out what is the difference between a [render pass](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap8.html) and a [pipeline](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap21.html) from their definitions.

What are they comparing to OpenGL?

As far as I can guess, render pass contains resources (or attachments) like vertex buffers, textures and probably sharers, and the shaders refers that resources by some ids that re valid withing a render pass. Am I thinking in a right direction?

The both render pass and pipeline contain commands and belong to some command buffer, right?

Then what is the pipeline for?

Answer (score 4):

A Vulkan pipeline is most similar to an OpenGL program object, but also includes additional state which is dynamically managed in OpenGL.

A Vulkan render pass is most similar to an OpenGL framebuffer object, but includes more explicit management of when rendering actually happens which was implicitly managed by the driver in OpenGL.

> ... render pass contains resources (or attachments) like vertex buffers, textures and probably shaders ...

At the API level the render pass directly defines the render pass attachments being used (i.e. what is being rendered in to). In the command stream it acts as a containing scope for draw commands. It is the draw commands that define which resources are used by a draw (program, vertex buffer, textures, etc), not the render pass itself.

> The both render pass and pipeline contain commands and belong to some command buffer, right?

Command buffers maintain the current state in use - similar to the context state in OpenGL (i.e. what program is currently active, what descriptor sets are current active, etc).

Command buffers contains commands that define a render pass scope (e.g. `vkCmd[Being/End]Renderpass()`). Within that scope you can issue draw commands (e.g. `vkCmdDrawIndexed()`). Draw commands will dispatch with the currently bound state, just like OpenGL.

Comment: In OpenGL multiple programs may be used to render into one framebuffer, so multiple pipelines can be used within one render pass scope in Vulkan, right?

Comment: Is there an active pipeline in a command buffer?

Comment: Yes - dynamically bound state, just like OpenGL via `vkCmdBindPipeline()`.

Comment: Render pass defines the image we draw into, right? Who of them does define what program, vertex buffer or texture is used?

Comment: Are program, vertex buffer and texture attachments that defined by the render pass?

Comment: Plenty of getting started info here: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/ ;P

Comment: Pipeline contains the shaders, Reder Pass defines vertex buffer and index buffer by vkCmdBind*